# while passing a comma separated string as a parameter to database

Tags: java, sql, database, sybase

i have a search field which search the data from back end sybase . if I pass one parameter .It search the data with calling stored procedure SYN_XYZ @param = "abc".
now if I pass two param It calls like SYN_XYZ @param = "abc,def"

Now consider a  situation , that back end data contain 'ab,c' instead of 'abc' . how can I search 'ab,c','def' As sybase will consider this param as three different param ie ab and c and def.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Don't use String concatenation. Instead, use `CallableStatement` and `setString()`.

Your solution is very, very dangerous. Imagine an attacker searching for `"; DELETE FROM USER; COMMIT;`